# Is it possible to use cin with Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, iostream, cin

Is it possible to use `cin` in Qt? I can use `cout` but cannot find examples of how to use `cin` within a Qt console application.

Answer (score 25):

I tested out [Kaleb Pederson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/103842/kaleb-pederson)'s answer, and found a more consise way than the solution he presented (though I have to thank him for pointing me to the right direction):

```
QTextStream qtin(stdin); 
QString line = qtin.readLine();  // This is how you read the entire line

QString word;
qtin >> word;    // This is how you read a word (separated by space) at a time.
```

In other words, you don't really need QFile as your middleman.

Comment: Coolbeans. I didn't like the idea of using "stdin" as a fake file.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it's possible and works as expected although you can do things, like use threads, that may cause problems with this approach.

However, I would recommend a more idiomatic (Qt) way to read from stdin:

```
QString yourText;
QFile file;
file.open(stdin, QIODevice::ReadOnly);
QTextStream qtin(&file);
qtin >> yourText;
```

Comment: And you can do similar with cout (qout). One of the larger benefits is the native support for many Qt types.

Answer (score 2):

I just tried the following code with QtCreator and it seems to be working :

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    cout << endl << "hello" << endl;
    int nb;
    cout << "Enter a number " << endl;
    cin>>nb;
    cout << "Your number is "<< nb<< endl;

    return a.exec();
```

}

Hope it helps a bit !

Comment: I think he is talking about using cin with certain qt objects especially QString not just ints.