# cin Equivalent in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to use CIN and QT ???](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321880/is-it-possible-to-use-cin-and-qt)

Hi
What is the cin equivalent in qt ?
thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you want a graphical input field or something like that ?

Comment: Do you have a console application or GUI? cin is still possible though

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent of `cin` in Qt is `cin`.

Comment: I would've bet on `qin`, simply for the sake of having a Q in front of everything.

Comment: How can I use it ? How can I give a  QString from user ?

Comment: @woody Are you looking for identical behaviour to cin?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cin`, if you want to get `QString` from the user see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321880/is-it-possible-to-use-cin-and-qt).