# Verification: Is entered - integer number? QT c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, qt, verification

Please help me with optimize the function of checking the entered value. Function returns true and sent value using link, if entered - integer, or returns false if entered char, string(empty). I think there are 2 ways to speed increase: eliminate the use of std::string or eliminate the use of QString.

```
bool tryRead(int &v)
{
    QString s;
    string s1;
    cin >> s1;
    s = QString::fromStdString(s1);
    if (s.isEmpty())
    {
        cout << "Error! You entered empty string";
        return false;
    }
    bool isNumber = true;
    v = ((s.toInt(&isNumber)));
    if(isNumber == false)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps not relevant, but in what situation would you need to optimize this? There's no way that this is the bottleneck of an application if you're actually taking user input.

Comment: Increasing speed. Reducing the number of calls to the variable. Now I called 2 times: s=QString::fromStdString(s1); v=((s.toInt(&isNumber))); I think if read QString or check string will faster.

Comment: How fast do you expect the user to type to have this make a difference?

Comment: Replacing the last 3 lines with `return isNumber;` will help me sleep at night.  Also using a `QIntValidator` is the preferred 'Qt' of way of doing this (https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtgui/qintvalidator.html).

Comment: You can read from cin to QString directly as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3018745/344347).

Answer (score 0):

This is what iostream operators are for.  A minimal implementation would be:

```
bool tryRead(int &v){
    cin >> v;
    return cin.good();
}
```

Depending on what you actually want to accomplish you may want to add some additional sanity checking, error handling and cleanup of cin.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `cin` and `cout` you can use `QTextStream`.

```
QTextStream cin(stdin), cout(stdout);
int myint;
cin >> myint;
if(cin.status() != QTextStream::Ok)
    cout << "It is not an integer!" << endl;
```

After detecting the error make sure to call `QTextStream::resetStatus()` to clean the error flags.