# is it possible to listen for commandline arguments at runtime for a GUI app in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, command-line, command-line-arguments

I am building an application that reads a text file for URL links to create website thumbnails.

What I would like is to be able to insert URL's into the textfile with PHP and then call the program to read the links and make thumbnails.

I could close the application when its finished processing and then simply call it again when needed but I think the application would be starting/closing a lot needlessly if there are lots of requests.

It would be better if I could controll the application through commandline arguments. I am not sure if this is possible?

I am trying to create a while loop to listen for commandline input

```
while(std::cin >> urlLink){

    qDebug() << "test";

}
```

Next I have tried adding: "CONFIG += console" to the .pro file but it doesnt show any commandline console.

I have no idea how to accomplish what I am trying to do. If you guys could help me out, I would be very glad.

**So my question is: Is it possible to have a GUI app that is controlled through the commandline? And how would I go about this? (In Qt)**

Comment: Command line arguments are only passed when the application starts, you need some other way of signaling the application to re-read the file. Alternatively, you could have the application monitor the file and look for changes (e.g. new modification timestamp, or different file-size, or using your platforms native file-monitoring interface).

Comment: So a PHP program "feeds" your program continously. a) Just adding lines to the file while the other program is reading it is a problem, forget this. b) Why your program needs a GUI?

Comment: But actually, first you really should check if it's worth running your program as a *daemon*, because you need continuous requests all day long for it to be worth turning your application into a daemon. Are you expecting the program to be called several time a minute for days on ends, or only a couple of time per day?

Comment: @deviantfan    Hi, thanks for replying! The program needs GUI capabilities because it renders a webpage and captures a screenshot of it. If I understood correctly, i can not do this while building a console app in Qt.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg good point! I do know for sure I will need to have it run continuously. So having it run as a Daemon would be awesome.

Comment: @deviantfan    also, if i get the console side working, i can drop the feeding through a file and simply feed the application through command lines. I already had a feeling that writing to a file with PHP while reading from the file with the thumbnail program would cause trouble

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I expect the program to be called for several times every minute.. That is what I am going for.

Comment: @CantThinkOfAnything As JoachimPileborg said already, the command line ist just relevant when the program starts. If you want something running all the time, you can´t use it while it runs. But ... with several times per *minute*, just start it separately for each URL, from PHP (and pass the URL as command line argument, instead of creating a file for it).

Comment: And keep in mind that you´ll need some plan how and where the results are saved so that one program instance won´t overwrite the result of others.

Comment: @deviantfan     hmm I see,,, Thanks for the input, i apreciate it a lot. It makes more sense indeed to do it like you suggest. I will make it so that the saved results are always unique so that they dont overwrite each other. And then just simply call the program each time for a given URL.

Comment: While it might not be the best solution, one way would be for your application to detect if another instance of it is already running. If not, launch normally, but if so, send a message to the already running application with the new information, and then just let the newly launched instance terminate after it sends the message.

Comment: @Steve          Hmm i see,, that way only one instance will always be handling the operations.. is that the point?

Comment: @CantThinkOfAnything Yep, exactly.

Comment: @Steve         good point then hehe! But for now, it does not really matter for me. If the number of operations performed increases, then I just might do what you suggested.

Comment: @CantThinkOfAnything Actually, I would think that this solution would really only be good when the number of operations is low. Creating a brand new process just to pass information to another process requires a pretty hefty overhead compared to other solutions.

Comment: @Steve         hmm yeah lol,, makes sense, It would cost less to simply stack the instances and let them die as they finish lol... apparently I did not use my head like i am supposed to in my previous comment hehe

Comment: @CantThinkOfAnything No, do not let the instances stack, that might even be worse, especially under heavy load.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88740/discussion-between-cantthinkofanything-and-steve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Joachim is right, you've confused command-line arguments, which are passed to your program before it enters main(), and console/command-line/teminal input and output, which is done using cin/cout, printf/scanf, etc. You can use cin and cout, this would be perfectly valid, but the Qt way to do it would be to use a QTextStream. See here for a discussion: [Is it possible to use cin with Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321880/is-it-possible-to-use-cin-with-qt)

I think it is perfectly doable in one thread but you might want to split your program into different QThreads, with one thread waiting on terminal input and then emitting a signal when it's read a link, and the other thread processing the links in the background. But, you could just do it linearly, i.e. read a link, process the link.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Right now I have made it so that the program is executed with a commandline argument. It processes the link and then it closes itself on finish. And then I just call it everytime i need it.. The answer you have given is a little more complex and I will defenitely refer to it if my program will need to handle more operations because as I have understood: with only a few calls per minute this simple way will suffice. Anyways, your answer is the correct one, Thanks!

Comment: No problem, you're right there, it can be difficult to remember to weigh-up developer time for the extra complication with running time for doing it the easy, less efficient way! QTextStreams are designed to be very much like the standard library's iostreams, so they shouldn't be too difficult if you end up giving them a spin. AFAIK their main attraction is better integration with Qt classes like QString, and that they  attempt to handle all the encoding issues internally, i.e. they will encode data from the platform's native format for text files into UTF-16 unicode like the whole of Qt uses.

Comment: I see. For Qt, the QTextStream definitely seems to be the way to go then.. going against it might be asking for trouble.. anyways you are right indeed, people sometimes forget to weigh up things.. and in this case it is most definitely better for me to keep it simple and focus on more important coding hehe :)